# How to check condition and click button in popup with Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriverwait

I have a case like this: I crawl one website but the website have a popup show random when the website show a popup I need it to wait 180 seconds. I want to check the condition popup and click to button for turn-off popup.

I want to ask: How to check the condition and click the button in popup with Selenium and Python but not have slow. I was can do that with my code but the time to find_element was too slow, it loses about 15-30 seconds for delay. This is my code:

The popup is random soo if when it does not show the popup. It will lose a lot of time in row find_element.

This is first code:

```
try:
    print('Try find Alert box')
    checkup_click_understand = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[3]/button')
    if checkup_click_understand.is_displayed():
        actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
        actions.click(checkup_click_understand)
        actions.perform()
        time.sleep(180)
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('No Alert BOX')
```

I tried another way but it has the same problem.
This is the second code:

```
try:
    print('Try find Alert box')
    # checkup_click_understand = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
    #     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[3]/button"))
    # )
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1)
    checkup_click_understand = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[3]/button')))
    print(checkup_click_understand.is_displayed())
    if checkup_click_understand.is_displayed():
        actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
        actions.click(checkup_click_understand)
        actions.perform()
        time.sleep(180)
except:
    print('No Alert BOX')
```

And the third code. I try to get the size to condition, but it same problem, take a lot of time when the code run to checkup_click_understand = WebDriverWait(driver, 3). I was think the code will work and I only need 3 seconds to wait, but it not, I need to spend 15-30s like the first and the second way.

```
try:
    print('Try find Alert box')
    checkup_click_understand = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[3]/button'))
    )
    if checkup_click_understand.size > 0:
        actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
        actions.click(checkup_click_understand)
        actions.perform()
        time.sleep(180)
except TimeoutException:
    print('No Alert BOX')
```

Answer (score 1):

WebDriverWait does not wait FOR 3 seconds, it waits UP TO 3 seconds. If the item appears before that it will click on it immediately.

for example: your popup appears after 15 seconds, but your wait is 20, your script will still click after 15 seconds; as soon as the popup appears.

with regard to clicking on the popup; item.click() doesn't work for you?

```
try:
    print('Try find Alert box')
    checkup_click_understand = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[3]/button')))
    checkup_click_understand.click()
    # if checkup_click_understand.size > 0:
    #     actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
    #     actions.click(checkup_click_understand)
    #     actions.perform()
    time.sleep(180)
except TimeoutException:
    print('No Alert BOX')
```

if not, this is how I would use action chains for simple click().

```
try:
    print('Try find Alert box')
    checkup_click_understand = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[3]/button')))
    #checkup_click_understand.click()
    if checkup_click_understand.size > 0:
        actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(checkup_click_understand).click().perform()
    time.sleep(180)
except TimeoutException:
    print('No Alert BOX')
```

Comment: Can you share with me a document about that? Why do you not use actions.click? I was thinking it same. I will test with your code share with me, thanks you so much!!!

Comment: I tried with your code. But it same with mine, it lost 15-30s in the row checkup_click_understand = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.ele.... Have some time for the reason DOM of the website?

Comment: You may need to send more of your code; the portion provided should work quickly if your xpath is provided; and at most 3-4 seconds if the xpath is not correct (or clickable).

Have you tried: EC.presence_of_element_located? 

Also, actionchains are used for sequences or combinations of inputs; click+drag, click in a certain spot; etc. check out more here: 

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much for supporting me! I will try again. I found the reason for this slow problem. The website I need automation has a slow server and DOM too big for selenium run and check, I am not sure 100% but I try with your code on a different page it works quickly.